# SSE `this.eventSource.onmessage` call fails. Error `"EventSource's response has a MIME type ("application/json") that is not "text/event-stream"

Tags: java, angular, spring-kafka, server-sent-events, spring-reactive

The Angular Server Sent Event `this.eventSource.onmessage` call fails with an error `"EventSource's response has a MIME type ("application/json") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection."` I see in the Chrome Dev Tools (image attached) that there are two `Content-Type` being returned. [image: Chrome DEv Tools Response Network Tab]

**Backend Code:Spring Reactor/REST**

```
    @GetMapping(value="/events",produces = "text/event-stream;charset=UTF-8")
    public Flux<ConsumerEvent> getProductEvents(){
        return kafkaService.getReceiverRecordAllFlux()
                .map(record->
                    new ConsumerEvent(record.topic(),record.value())
                );
        }
}
```

***Front end:Angular***

```
public startKafkaTopicInfoEventSource(): void {
    let url = BASE_URL;
    this.eventSource = new EventSource(url); 
    this.eventSource.onmessage = (event) => {//Error: EventSource's response has a MIME type ("application/json") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection
        this.zone.run(() => {
        // some code here
      })

    }
// other code here
}
```

The method `this.eventSource.onmessage` gives an error `EventSource's response has a MIME type ("application/json") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection.`

Any help would be great!

Comment: Your produces tag should be doing the right thing. Try using produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM instead, like in the example here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-server-sent-events ?

Comment: @MyStackRunnethOver Hi, I already did that. But the problem persists. If you see the image I attached in the Question I get two Content-Type values . Not sure why? When I check the end point in browser http://localhost:8181/events I get the output successfully as in the updated image I have attached just now. The problem lies in calling the REST Url over angular client. Not sure though where excactly.

Comment: That's odd. What happens if you remove `;charset=UTF-8`?

Comment: Yeah. onmessage gives this issue. If I remove the charset I guess I'll still get the same problem. I'll check that though.

Comment: have you tried returning a `ServerSentEvent` instead of `ConsumerEvent` a SSE needs to have a specific format. Try `ServerSentEvent.<ConsumerEvent>builder().data(new ConsumerEvent(record.topic(),record.value())).build()`

Comment: did you find any solution for the same @raikumardipak ? I have similar issue.

Comment: @ParvindraSingh i did not again get time to work upon it to my regret

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem using ASP.NET (and nodeJS).

I don't know if this helps but I experienced that, if you use [Moesif Origin & CORS Changer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-origin-cors-change/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc) (in the standard configuration, I didn't test custom one) some Headers get added or overwritten (the "new" one is chosen) by the plugin (at least Content-Type and X-Content-Type-Options) as we see in your Dev Tool Screenshot.

So Maybe some plugin you installed in Chrome causes this. Try running in a different Browser or without Plugins.

Hope I can help somebody and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, somewhere in your eventSource.onmessage, the code change MIME type value to  `{'content-type': 'application/json'}`, you have to keep it with the value of `{'content-type':'text/event-stream'}`