# React App: EventSource's response has a MIME type ("application/json") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, http-headers

Refactoring my app to use a new price API and I'm getting the following error:

> EventSource's response has a MIME type ("application/json") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection.

The free API doc for `/currencies/ticker` http://docs.nomics.com/#tag/Currencies

Here is my code after I added `'Content-type': 'text/event-stream'`

```
const headers: IHeaders = {
  baseURL: NOMICS_API_BASE_URL, // 'https://api.nomics.com/v1/'
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream'
  },
  params: {
    key: NOMICS_KEY
  }
}

// * GET Currencies
export const getCurrenciesRequest = async () => {
  console.log('getCurrenciesRequest...')
  const nomics = axios.create(headers)

  try {
    const currencies = await nomics.get(`currencies/ticker&ids=BTC,ETH,XRP&interval=1d,30d&convert=USD`)
    console.log('currencies', currencies)
    return currencies
  } catch (err) {
    return err
  }
}
```

Also just tried

```
const currencies = await axios.get(`https://api.nomics.com/v1/currencies/ticker?key=demo-26240835858194712a4f8cc0dc635c7a&ids=BTC,ETH,XRP&interval=1d,30d&convert=USD`)
```

and lower cased key
`'content-type': 'text/event-stream'`

Not sure what I'm missing, hoping for some thoughts here...

### UPDATE

I am able to get the response back now by removing `axios.create(headers)`

```
export const getCurrenciesRequest = async () => {
  console.log('getCurrenciesRequest...')

  try {
    const currencies = await axios.get(`https://api.nomics.com/v1/currencies/ticker?key=demo-26240835858194712a4f8cc0dc635c7a&ids=BTC,ETH,XRP&interval=1d,30d&convert=USD`)
    console.log('currencies', currencies)
    return currencies
  } catch (err) {
    return err
  }
}
```

However I still get the same error

> EventSource's response has a MIME type ("application/json") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection.

[image]

Comment: Did you try skipping `Content-Type` header?

Comment: @Rayon Yes I got that error when I didn't have Content-Type or a headers object.

Comment: What is the outcome of `const currencies = await axios.get(`https://api.nomics.com/v1/currencies/ticker?key=demo-26240835858194712a4f8cc0dc635c7a&ids=BTC,ETH,XRP&interval=1d,30d&convert=USD`)`. I tried this and it worked. I guess some other global configuration is affecting/breaking this.

Comment: Do you have any other network request where you are using `EventSource`?

Comment: @Rayon I am able to get the response back now! Also noticed that I get the error on line 1 `http://localhost/:1`

Comment: Happy coding ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you using a CORS extension? I had this issue as well and ran across this post: [SSE `this.eventSource.onmessage` call fails. Error `"EventSource's response has a MIME type ("application/json") that is not "text/event-stream"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61546705/sse-this-eventsource-onmessage-call-fails-error-eventsources-response-has)

You may need to disable the CORS extension to remove that console error.